# Generate unique transaction id from current datetime

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime, unique

I need to generate an unique transaction id using datetime in PHP. It should be around 17-20 character in number format. (**Like:** **2017041914495412346**)

 Can anyone please help out? 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you not just combine the date and time into a string, as you appear to have done here, then use a for loop to add a new integer onto the end until the length is 20 characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would work for you:

```
    <?php
function getGUIDnoHash(){
            mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);
            $charid = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
            $c = unpack("C*",$charid);
            $c = implode("",$c);

            return substr($c,0,20);
    }


echo getGUIDnoHash();
?>
```

Since you said characters, this will include only numeric. And will be 20 chars. Of course since it's numbers only and limited to 20 characters , this is not unique for ever, so you need to add a check to your code.

Comment: Hi Simos. Thanks for your suggestion. Sorry I mentioned character. I need  in number format. Can you please suggest me in number format?Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As like as I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use uniqid() function for that [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the unique transaction id like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssfff") ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can it do using several methods or date time logics. Below is single line solution with 17 digits which i am using

```
$unique = str_replace(".","",microtime(true)).rand(000,999);
```